# dangers of using WAMPServer on my home PC?

Tags: webserver, databases, web-hosting

Hello there I have been working on (learning) web development and have gone down the route of self hosting at the moment. I have a website which I've made, it doesnt have any user interface for input, but it does have a database which holds articles by genre etc.

I don't want to publicly post the url here for it as I fear perhaps people might see it as an easy target but I was just hoping that maybe an experienced user of the site would take a look at it for me if I pm'd them.

It's on my home PC, I use it via a router with some ports forwarded. The website loads fine etc. I have 3 disks on PC and the webserver is WAMPserver and is on the 3rd disk drive.

If not, is there anything I should watch out for in the small amount of php code I've written . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port forwarding to your PC is almost always a bad idea. Also to run a webserver on the machine. If configured wrongly, which could well be the case, it could leak out a lot of personal information to the internet, in your case mainly to automated port scanners/attackers. Not to even begin with the problems of exposing a windows machine to the public internet (even if it's for single ports). If I were you I would either not forward a port and set up a local name for the server under which I could reach it, or at least set up the webserver on a different machine on the same LAN and port forward that - but not under windows, on linux or bsd. You could also use some cheap VPS and set up SSL certificates for a test domain to encrypt your traffic over the public net.

And don't trust random people wanting to look at your webserver, they could just as well look for easy targets.

TLDR: Close the ports! Think again if this is really what you want to do.
Consider more secure and more "state of the art" options than self-hosting
a public test site on your own PC.

Comment: OK man thanks for this. I will not do it on my main pc. I have an old pc lying about that I could connect up and use instead after a new install. thanks for your advice

Comment: btw i actually dont need any ports forwarded for the server, but I have ports forwarded for gaming purposes. Is this also a bad idea then?

Comment: Well, generally, yes, personally I never had to forward any port to my local PC for any game, and don't have much experience with that. Maybe there are cases where it is really required, maybe it could be handled differently in a more secure fashion. I don't know. Maybe it's an issue for another question, to keep things concentrated on the question here,